# Issue implementing google autocomplete in vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm trying to use google auto complete in vue.js with laravel but it is giving me error :

> ```
> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: google is not defined" 
> found in
> ---> <VueGoogleAutocomplete> at /src/components/VueGoogleAutocomplete.vue
>        <App> at /src/App.vue
>
>          <Root>
> ```

here is the link to the code which i'm trying to implement:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-bardeen-5eock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking your codesandbox, I noticed that you didn't include the Google Maps Places API in the head tag of your public/index.html.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: I'm using it in laravel and i don't have index.html file in public folder, i was trying to pass key in main.js

Comment: I suppose that you have at least blade template for layout or current page which is using google map, and you can insert above script tag into blade template.